# How to use the NumPy string formatter to print a NumPy array where the output string is dependent on the array value?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, formatting

I want to print a string depending on the values in a NumPy array, e.g. value `0` should lead to letter `'a'`.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.zeros((2,2))
arr[(0,0)] = 1
arr[(0,1)] = 2
printValues = {0:'a', 1:'b', 2:'c'}
print(np.array2string(arr, formatter={'str':lambda x: printValues[x]}))
```

**Expected result:**

```
[['b' 'c']
 ['a' 'a']]
```

**Observed:**

```
[[1. 2.]
 [0. 0.]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword argument `formatter` for [`array2string`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array2string.html) needs the type of the elements of the array which you want to replace, not the type which you're converting to.

So, in your example, instead of `str` you should use `float`, since `0.`, `1.` and `2.` are floats.

If you want to make sure, every element of the array is definitely printed with your formatter, use `all`:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.zeros((2, 2))
arr[(0, 0)] = 1
arr[(0, 1)] = 2
printValues = {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}
print(np.array2string(arr, formatter={'all': lambda x: printValues[int(x)]}))
```

See the above linked documentation for more available types. Maybe `float_kind` is also a good idea for you.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC `vectorize`

```
np.vectorize(printValues.get)(arr)
array([['b', 'c'],
       ['a', 'a']], dtype='<U1')
```